# How to use join (in built method) in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

In javascript loop i am generating a `xml` like this:

```
for (m = 0; m < t.length; m++) {
     var arr1 = t[m].split("\t");
     s = "'<row dc= '" + arr1[0] + "' al='" + arr1[1] + "' msg='" + arr1[2] + "' />'";
     alert(s);
     //s = s.join(' '); 
    }
```

Forgot about the `t` variable and all. by run this code i am getting the s value in the following format:

```
<row dc = "abc" al="56" msg="dkaj" />
```

In the second iteration it shows like this:

```
<row dc = "abwwc" al="56w" msg="dkajad" />
```

and so on till the `m<t.length` satisfy. What i want to join the list in each iteration. After joining all of them i should get in this way:

```
<row dc = "abc" al="56" msg="dkaj" /><row dc = "abwwc" al="56w" msg="dkajad" /> and so on..
```

I tried to do it with join written in comment section, but didn't work for me. What i am doing wrong?

Comment: Join merges an array into a string. This is not what you're after. Use `+` or `+=` to append stuff to your `s` variable.

Comment: @zneak I am beginner in java script, but i tried with join but it didn't work for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way would be to define a string outside the loop an append to it;

```
var v = '';
for (m = 0; m < t.length; m++) {
     var arr1 = t[m].split("\t");
     s = "'<row dc= '" + arr1[0] + "' al='" + arr1[1] + "' msg='" + arr1[2] + "' />'";
     alert(s);
     v += s;
    }

alert(v);
```

If you still want to use `join()`, make `v` an array and `push()` elements on to it (note that `join()` is an **array** method, not for string's)

```
var y = [];
for (m = 0; m < t.length; m++) {
     var arr1 = t[m].split("\t");
     s = "'<row dc= '" + arr1[0] + "' al='" + arr1[1] + "' msg='" + arr1[2] + "' />'";
     alert(s);
     y.push(s);
    }

alert(y.join(''));
```

You'll be pleased to see I've tried to adhere to your variable naming conventions in my examples (i.e. meaningless characters).